# boost::iostream readline stop after 4096 bytes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing a program that transfer large data over network and I'm using boost asio iostream to do it.

here's my code :

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s;
s.connect("localhost","4000"); 
string ss;
getline(s,ss);
```

but getline does not read a complete line when output is more than 4096 charachters and it break it into two messages.

what is the right way to read a single line when input is large?

Comment: What operating system is that? Is it truly on local host or is network infrastructure involved? (NICs, cables, switches?). On my box it works exactly as advertised, no (apparent) limit

Comment: os is linux, no it's truly localhost.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the sender? **EDIT:** Also how does it compare with `char c; while(s.get(c)) ss += c;`

Comment: @Galik that should work, in fact it works with `while(getline(s,tmp)) ss += tmp` the way I read the question

Comment: @sehe Ah yes I should have put a line end check in there: `char c; while(s.get(c) && c != '\n') ss += c;`

Comment: I think this way is too slow. every get is a systemcall isn't it?

Comment: @MohammadRazeghi no, every get is an operation on the stream buffer. Now, when the buffer underflows, that should be a syscall, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not reproducing this with

- Ubuntu linux 14.10 64 bit
- gcc 4.8.2
- boost_1_57
- localhost traffic

***Did you check there are no linefeeds in the input?***

---

If I feed it a continues stream of input, I do not detect such issues. E.g. with netcat, **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf19703567c0db89)**

```
for a in {1..1024}; do echo -n 0123456789; done | nc -l 6767&
```

This sends 10k of data without linefeeds

```
./a.out | wc
```

This counts lines, words and characters returned by our code:

```
 0       1   10240
```

### Code

for reference

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream socket("127.0.0.1","6767"); 

    std::string as_read;
    std::getline(socket,as_read);

    std::cout << as_read;
}
```

Comment: I've just tried your code and your bash script. and I have the same problem. my gcc version is 4.9.2 and localhost traffic. on archlinux

Comment: Let's start calling it "behaviour" instead of a problem then. Is there something in `ulimit -a`? What boost and kernel versions?

Comment: my boost version is 1.57.0-2 and this is my `ulimit -a` output : http://pastebin.com/0PXKNJpv. my kernel version is `3.14.25-1-lts`. besides I want my code to run on every computer without changing anything.

Comment: Wokay. Seems recent enough. In the ulimits there _is_ `pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8` (8*512 == 4096...) but [coliru has the same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a756d507e264c600), and pipes shouldn't really be involved. Mmm. _Interesting_

Comment: I've just installed my first Arch ever just to test this: **[demo animation gif](http://downloads.sehe.nl/stackoverflow/q27196913.gif)** - that is with stock kernel and fresh install. Just installed `base-devel vim boost openbsd-netcat screen` for this demo. I strongly suspect some non-standard issues at play (SELinux, AppArmor, iptables, sysctl tunings whatnot).

Comment: I don't know what the problem was but I've just upgrade my system and reboot and everything seems fine. thanks..

Comment: What does that entail, exactly? Did you upgrade boost? The compiler? Just the OS? Which kernel are you on now? Is there a difference in (emulated) hardware? Did you install (the same/other version of) the virtual machine guest additions?

Comment: (Oh, thanks for reporting back, of course. If this information leads to clues that are helpful to the community, you might consider posting an answer - so that we can make it searchable. In that case I suggest we unaccept this answer and move the accept to the winning clue :))

Comment: I've checked my package manager log and it seems that the kernel upgraded from 3.14.24-1 to 3.14.25-1. and my OS is not emulated.

Comment: Do you mean you moved to a physical host? (When running virtual machines the hardware is being emulated)

Comment: No i didn't move. I was on physical host from beginning.

Comment: @MohammadRazeghi Oh I'm sorry, I'm confusing it with another trouble shooting question - possibly because _I_ did some testing on a VM. Sorry for the confusion. Still interesting to know whether kernel fixed something :) Cheers again for updating